# How can I set up two navigation properties of the same type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

With code first EF4 (using CTP5) I can add a single navigation property along with the foreign key and it will respect the naming and only add the foreign key to the table a single time. If I then go and add a second property of the same type, it breaks it down into 4 columns on the table instead of just two.

Sample code:

With this model, I get a single property added to the AdapterFrameCapability table for PressType named PressTypeID.

```
public class AdapterFrameCapability
{
    [Key]
    public int AdapterFrameCapabilityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PressTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual PressType PressType { get; set; }
}
```

This is the setup I want to model, but it results in 4 columns being created in the table, one each for FromPressTypeID, FromPressTypeFromPressTypeID, ToPressTypeID and ToPressTypePressTypeID. Ideally I'd just like a column for FromPressTypeID and ToPressTypeID. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class AdapterFrameCapability
{
    [Key]
    public int AdapterFrameCapabilityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FromPressTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "From Press Type")]
    public virtual PressType FromPressType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ToPressTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To Press Type")]
    public virtual PressType ToPressType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's one of those scenarios that you need to drop down [fluent API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx) to get the desired schema:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AdapterFrameCapability>()
                .HasRequired(afc => afc.FromPressType)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(afc => afc.FromPressTypeID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AdapterFrameCapability>()
                .HasRequired(afc => afc.ToPressType)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(afc => afc.ToPressTypeID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Switching cascade delete off on one of the associations is intentional because *otherwise* SQL Server would throw out the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'AdapterFrameCapability_ToPressType' on table 'AdapterFrameCapabilities' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint.

So we need to switch it off on one of the associations like the way I did in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were suppose to use the data annotation attribute

```
public class AdapterFrameCapability
{
    [Key]
    public int AdapterFrameCapabilityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FromPressTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "From Press Type")]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(FromPressTypeId))]
    public virtual PressType FromPressType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ToPressTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To Press Type")]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ToPressTypeID))]
    public virtual PressType ToPressType { get; set; }
}
```