# EF multiple properties referencing same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to link a list of subs and a main sub for a video object with cascade on delete.

I found some pages explaining how to do this for 2 single objects to the same type. But not for a list and a single object.
[How can I set up two navigation properties of the same type in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429103/how-can-i-set-up-two-navigation-properties-of-the-same-type-in-entity-framework)

Here is my code:

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class SimpleVideo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int SimpleVideoId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Sub> Subs { get; set; }
        public Sub MainSub { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sub
    {
        public int SubId { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }

    class VideoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SimpleVideo> SimpleVideos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sub> Subs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<VideoContext>());

            modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleVideo>().HasMany(v => v.Subs).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleVideo>().HasOptional(v => v.MainSub).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get this to work.
when i enable just one of the modelBuilder lines, it works.
How do i get both of them to work at the same time?

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed. [ Constraint name = FK_dbo.Subs_dbo.SimpleVideos_SubId ]
  Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeError=25083
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr& pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(Boolean skipExistsCheck)
       at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create()
       at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
       at System.Data.Entity.Database.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
       at DataAccess.Program.Main() in c:\MMProject\TestProjects\DataAccess\Program.cs:line 63
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What is one of the modelBuilder line?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post of mine **dealing with the exact same structure** (as far as I can tell)...
[Entity Framework One-to-Many with Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751798/entity-framework-one-to-many-with-default/15754234#15754234)

I didn't test this - so just replaced names - this should work I think...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleVideo>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.MainSub)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal() // x => x.DefaultForEntity)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

You don't need the other one relationship - cascade is on by default.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. The classes used here are just to test the scenario. The two properties are completely independent and the object in the MainSub property is not present in the list Subs. So MainSub is not a "default".

Comment: it doesn't matter what's the `semantics` - your data looks just like that.