# Model haivng same entity multiple times with bidirection navigation properties

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

There is a one-to-one relationship between Measurement and Observation, however an Observation has both a "before" and "after" measurement.  This works ok as long as I don't need a navigation property to go back from the measurement to the observation.  Entity can't resolve the Measurement.observation property which causes the normalizedValue property to raise a NullPointer exception.

*Edit:* Edited to try to include comments from [How can I set up two navigation properties of the same type in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429103/how-can-i-set-up-two-navigation-properties-of-the-same-type-in-entity-framework) but still not working.

```
public class Measurement
{
    [Key]
    public int measurementId { get; set; }
    public int val1 { get; set; }

    public virtual Observation observation { get; set; }

    public float noramlizedValue { get { return val1 / observation.normalizationFactor; } }
}

public class Observation
{
    [Key]
    public int observationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int beforeMeasId { get; set; }
    public virtual Measurement before { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int afterMeasId { get; set; }
    public virtual Measurement after { get; set; }

    public int normalizationFactor { get; set; }
}

public class Model1 : DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<Observation> observations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Observation>()
            .HasRequired(o => o.before)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.beforeMeasId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Observation>()
            .HasRequired(o => o.after)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.afterMeasId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new Model1())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            var o1 = new Observation
            {
                before = new Measurement { val1 = 5 },
                after = new Measurement { val1 = 10 },
                normalizationFactor = 3
            };
            db.observations.Add(o1);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Before: ");
            Console.WriteLine(o1.before.noramlizedValue);  // Raises null reference exception
            Console.WriteLine("After: ");
            Console.WriteLine(o1.after.noramlizedValue);

        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up two navigation properties of the same type in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429103/how-can-i-set-up-two-navigation-properties-of-the-same-type-in-entity-framework)

Comment: I've tried setting up using the link you provided but still did not get it to work.

Comment: Still the same exception?

Comment: Yes: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred.  Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Didn't you accidentally turned off `LazyLoading`?

Comment: Added db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; to be sure.  No change.

Comment: You must create one-to-zero(or one) relation, not one-to-many.