# Entity Framework - Retrieve different values according to foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I'm new working with EF and a have this scenario:
Classes:

```
public class Step
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Workflow
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int stepID { get; set; }
    public int nextStepID { get; set; }

    public virtual Step Step
}
```

What I want to know is if have a way to get "name" from class Step based on stepID and nextStepID. 
I know that I can do that

```
var result = (from Workflow in db.Workflow
              join Step in db.Step on Workflow.stepID equals Step.ID               
              join nextStep in db.Step on Workflow.nextStepID equals nextStep.ID
              select new
              {
                 nameStep = Step.name,
                 nameNextStep = nextStep.name
              }
             ).ToList();
```

but this way i'm not retrieving a Workflow entity.

I'm wondering if is possible to do something like that "automatically" using EF to retrieve a Workflow entity with Step and Next Step name.

I hope that's clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the WorkFlow entity in the anonymous type like this:

```
select new
{
    Workflow = Workflow,
    nameStep = Step.name,    
    nameNextStep = nextStep.name
}
```

You might want to consider modeling the `Workflow` entity in such a way that it has two navigational properties to `Step`. One for the `stepID` foreign key and one for the `nextStepID` foreign key. This will make your queries simpler. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429103/how-can-i-set-up-two-navigation-properties-of-the-same-type-in-entity-framework).

Comment: I thought about change my model but , like the link you've posted, I'll need to use Fluent API, as I'm new in EF, I'm not used to use Fluent API so I need to understand this first to know how to use and retrieve the information I want it. I'll look  later. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: just to let you know: using fluent API works perfect! ;)