# How can I include two relational properties of the same type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, relational-database, code-first

I have an ApplicationUser model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

... and a Project model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProjectCreatorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProjectOwnerId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ProjectCreator { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ProjectOwner { get; set; }
    public Project ParentProject { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Project> ChildProjects { get; set; }
}
```

In `OnModelCreating()`, I tried this:

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasMany(c => c.ChildProjects)
    .WithOne(p => p.ParentProject)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentProjectId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Projects)
    .WithOne(o => o.ProjectOwner)
    .HasForeignKey(po => po.ProjectOwnerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Projects)
    .WithOne(c => c.ProjectCreator)
    .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.ProjectCreatorId);
```

But upon creating the database, I get

> Cannot create a relationship between 'ApplicationUser.Projects' and 'Project.ProjectCreator', because there already is a relationship between 'ApplicationUser.Projects' and 'Project.ProjectOwner'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

I tried the solutions to [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429103/how-can-i-set-up-two-navigation-properties-of-the-same-type-in-entity-framework), but wasn't able to make any of them work.

Is there another way I could keep track of both a `Project`'s creator AND owner, and be able to `.Include()` them both in the queries?

Comment: You need two navigation properties in `ApplicationUser` like `OwnedProjects` and `CreatedProjects` as you cannot use `Projects` twice for different relationships.

Comment: Alternatively you could put a table between them that included columns to specify if the user owns and/or created the project.  That way you wouldn't have potentially duplicated projects linked to the same user twice.

Comment: @juharr I think I'll try the linking table approach. Thanks for reminding me of their existance! ;) I'll post an update later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of different binding, use the single binding

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
.HasMany(p => p.Projects)
.WithOne(o => o.ProjectOwner)
.HasForeignKey(po => po.ProjectOwnerId);
.WithOne(c => c.ProjectCreator)
.HasForeignKey(pc => pc.ProjectCreatorId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I went for this solution:

As mentioned in the comments, `ApplicationUser` would need two `List<Project>`-properties:

```
public List<Project> CreatedProjects { get; set; }
public List<Project> OwnedProjects { get; set; }
```

Then, in `OnModelCreating()`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasOne(g => g.ProjectCreator)
    .WithMany(t => t.CreatedProjects)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProjectCreatorId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasOne(g => g.ProjectOwner)
    .WithMany(t => t.OwnedProjects)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProjectOwnerId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
    .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
```

Now I'm able to include both creators and owners. :)